# add_editor_style to the blog editor view (Gutenberg?)

Tags: plugin-development, add-editor-style

How do I include a css **from a custom plugin** that would take effect when editing the post? (I assume now the WP blog editing page are all using Gutenberg)

I got this code during my research my it is not working for me at all:

```
function ghub_child_setup() {
    // Add support for editor styles.
    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
  
    // Enqueue editor styles.
    add_editor_style( 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ghub_child_setup' );
```

I have replace the css path with the following, not working...

```
add_editor_style( plugins_url( 'css/editor.css', __FILE__) . '?ver=' . rand(0,100) );
```

I also found this code, still not working for me

//

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
 
function plugin_mce_css( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';
 
    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'css/editor.css', __FILE__ );
 
    return $mce_css;
}
```

Comment: Your first two blocks of code look correct. But what's the structure of your plugin files? And how have you confirmed that it's not working? If you look at the Network tab of your developer tools is the stylesheet URL appearing? Is it correct? Or are the styles just not applying? Have you rules out a CSS specificity issue?

Comment: Styles not applying, and then I looked at the source code and my stylesheet is not being included at the edit post page, so for sure it is not working for me.

Comment: the editor.css file is located at " {my plugin_folder}\css\editor.css} , add_editor_style( plugins_url( 'css/editor.css', __FILE__)); seems like the correct file path. I placed the entire block of code inside my main plugin php file...